# Asset Browser - Dynamic Refresh from a file to an other?

Tags: asset-browser

I'm stating to use Asset browser and discover the potential of this !
This is very cool !
So i'm trying to :
1 - Create a Mark asset from a "Blendfile_A"
2 - Automatically import them into an other "Blendfile_B"

But i saw that i always need to refresh the "Blendfile_B" or close and reopen it.

Is this suppose to happened ? Should it be more dynamic ?
I know this is kind of new so bug and improvement are to be expect but i'm curious if i miss something or not :)[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the normal behaviour, and I don't expect it to change in the future. An Asset Browser library can contain thousands of assets, located in thousands of files.

You can't expect the current blend file to scan all the files constantly and refresh the asset list, that would be terrible for the user experience. Sure, it would work for a few files and a few assets overall, but it wouldn't scale well at all.

You could however use a python script that periodically fetches all assets in the library, but I really wouldn't recommend it.

The expected workflow if you want to add an asset to a library file is to right click on the asset > Open Blend file, then add the asset to the library file and close the file, which will take you back to file 1 and refresh the list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)
I'm looking into make a pipeline with a cool user experience for artist. and i'm wondering what's the best way for them to use asset Lib.
If doing R to refresh is a valid manipulation that's totally ok :)

Thanks a lot Gorgious !